# How to Use Variable as the Key

Tags: string, wordpress, variables, metadata

If I use a String for the $key my code works but if I use $hasorhasnotentered it  returns "Array". How can I use a Variable for the $key?

```
<?php 
  $user_id = $current_user->ID;
  $key = $hasorhasnotentered;
  $single = true;
  $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
  echo '<p>The '. $key . ' value for user id ' . $user_id . ' is: ' . $user_last . '</p>'; 
?>
```

The Variable is being defined by user interaction of a form below is the form code

```
<form method="post" id="adduser" action="/my-likes-list/">

<input type="text" name="<?php echo $hasorhasnotentered;?>" id="<?php echo $hasorhasnotentered;?>" value="<?php echo $yesentered; ?>"/>   

 <p class="form-submit">
        <input name="updateuser" type="submit" id="updateuser" class="submit button" value="update-user" onclick='enterdnew()'/>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-user' ) ?>
    <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="Update" />
</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable just as you did.  It's just that the variable needs to contain a string.  Evidently, your `$hasorhasnotentered` contains.  That explains why it would return an array because if $key is left blank `get_user_meta` returns all of the meta data in an array.  See the documentation:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

`$key
(string) (optional) The meta_key in the wp_usermeta table for the meta_value to be returned. If left empty, will return all user_meta fields for the given user.
Default: (empty string)`

Edit:
In the form code above, I believe you want:

`<input type="text" name="hasorhasnotentered" id="hasorhasnotentered" value="<?php echo $hasorhasnotentered; ?>"/>`

Then, on load, the value of the element will be set to whatever $hasorhasnotentered is.  And the user will set $hasorhasnotentered to be whatever text they type in the element.

Then, on submit, $hasorhasnotentered will be the text of the input field.

I have to admit, I may not be understanding the intent of your code.

Comment: When I use var_dump I get "Null" but that is not true because when I use the string instead of the variable I get the correct results.

Comment: Check in your code for the place where you set the value of $hasorhasnotentered.  I guarantee you that it is not being set correctly.  If you show the code where you define it, perhaps we could help you figure out *why* it isn't getting set with the value you expect it to have in it.

Comment: its defined by user interaction in a form

Comment: Then your problem is that you are not receiving the form data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK, but I expect your $hasorhasnotentered variable is not undefined. If it's value comes from user input check for definedness before you use  it!